# Animation Nodes - How to make text gallop like horses and next stumble like drunks?

Tags: animation-nodes

At first, I attempted to make text stumble slowly into scene like drunken sailors, but I ended up with the galloping text that runs like horses; nonetheless, I like the effect. 
In all three examples below, all letters are individually done on separate layers and all have same animation. In second & third examples, I've spaced out letters by only shifting frames to the right on timeline, without ever changing animation of letters or their speeds.

Now how do I mimic the galloping examples below with Animation Nodes? 
And next, how do I slow down their speed so to make them seem drunken and clumsy? This is for future projects with motion graphics.

Assistance appreciated. Thanks in advance.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Rita. I currently don't have Animation Nodes on my system for a certain reason. So I can't answer this question right now. However, don't you think that this is similar, if not identical, to the example we made where the characters followed a sine wave? It seems increasing the frequency and reducing the amplitude would give the required result, don't you think?

Comment: No worries, and thanks for answering. I will try out your suggestion. I will figure out.